# How to control url once share button facebook clicks

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I got a for loop data where in each has a facebook share button, my goal is when the user clicks on the share button it will direct to its assigned page.

heres my share button div:

```
<img id = "share_button" src="img/share.png">
```

fb code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#share_button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   FB.ui(
 {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
    link: ' http://www.test.com/',
    picture: '',
    caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
    description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
    message: ''
    });
   });
 });
 </script>
```

is there a way i can edit the ajax script to something like this:

```
 link: ' http://www.test.com/test.php?id="<?php echo $id; ?> ',
```

Comment: When will people stop developing facebook stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach can be this that you store $id as an attribute with image like this:

```
<img id = "share_button" src="img/share.png" page_id=<?php echo $id?>/>
```

and then do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#share_button').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).attr('page_id');
   FB.ui(
 {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
    link: ' http://www.test.com/test.php?id='+ id,
    picture: '',
    caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
    description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
    message: ''
    });
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Note that this will work if you are generating HTML usinh PHP.

Comment: Hi mishra! im getting error on this part:  link: ' http://www.test.com/test.php?id='+ id', i think the error is the apostrophe

Comment: im getting this url http://test.com.au/test.php?id=%27id%27     but its almost close

Comment: This may be due to encoding..Does fb does encoding of the link provided?

Comment: @user2434677 I think it is takink '$id' like this, thats why extra quotes are coming.

Comment: Please at least make that a `data` attribute, instead of polluting the HTML with arbitrary attributes.